# Does an analytical solution to integral exist?

Tags: integration

In the absence of finding an analytical solution to the integral of $y= \exp(-x\cosh(x))\sin(x)$ over the interval $0$ to $1$, I resorted to a numerical solution. This prompted the question, can a analytical solution be found ?

If anyone can find one, I would be grateful if they would share. In the mean time I will try and find one, although I am not optimistic.

Comment: Integral is similar to: $\int x^x \, dx$. I doubt there's a closed form.